Hibernate is telling me my entity's id field "doesn't have a default value" even though I have @GeneratedValue and @Id on the field
I saw many answers to this question, none of which illuminated my issue. I've tried several configurations of my setup with little success.
Here is my expected result: I can put a new Cart object into cartRepository.save(someNewCart) and the new cart is inserted into the database.
My actual result is that the error message java.sql.SQLException: Field 'cart_id' doesn't have a default value is shown to me.
I don't get that error message. It looks nonsensical to me, given:
@Entity
@Table(name = "carts")
@Data
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cart_id")
    private Long id;

  @Column(name = "orderTrackingNumber")
    private String orderTrackingNumber;

    @Column(name = "package_price")
    private BigDecimal package_price;

    @Column(name = "party_size")
    private int party_size;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private StatusType status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<CartItem> cartItems;

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date createdAt;
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private Date lastUpdate;
}

I would think that that would be sufficient.
I have a simple repository implementation:

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "cart", path = "cart")
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public interface CartRepository extends JpaRepository<Cart, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Cart c WHERE c.id = (SELECT MAX(cc.id) FROM Cart cc)")
    Cart findCartWithHighestId();
}

That I use by writing cartRepository.saveAndFlush(cart);
The cart table is created with
CREATE TABLE `carts` (
    `cart_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    // a few lines down:
    PRIMARY KEY (`cart_id`),

so it is definitely an autoincrementing value.
Among the posts I examined about this, people suggest:
"Assign a default value" => I don't want to do that and anyway it doesn't work
"The error is self explainable, it does mean their is "not null constraint" for "name" in db and you are not setting any value against the column." => But I expect JPA/SQL to do it for me. That's the goal.
"recreating the database solved the problem" => I tried that, fails. The same post has someone saying to set the GeneratedValue strategy to IDENTITY, that fails for me.
I have a dozen more tabs open. The code all looks right to me, which suggests I'm not looking at something outside of the current set of considered sources of the error. Hence I wonder if I should be posting some other portion of the program that I'm not showing, or if some crucial component is missing.
Here is some code showing the cart's origination in the program:
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public PurchaseDataResponse placeOrder(PurchaseDTO purchase) {
        System.out.println("\n))))\n((((\nThe Purchase:");
        System.out.println(purchase.toString());
        Cart cart = purchase.getCart();
        Integer partySize = cart.getPartySize();
        cart.startCartItemSet();


// in another file

public class PurchaseDTO {
    private Customer customer;
    private Cart cart;
    private Set<CartItem> cartItems;

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public Cart getCart() {
        return cart;
    }

    public Set<CartItem> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    public CartItem getFirstCartItem() {
        if (cartItems.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return cartItems.iterator().next();
    }
}


I'll show a normal console log output of a cart item
Cart{
    id=0,
    orderTrackingNumber='5597d6843f254f',
    package_price=1100.00,
    party_size=1,
    status=pending,
    customer=Customer[id=6, firstName='Tatiana', lastName='Petrova'],
    cartItems=[
    CartItem {id=2,
 vacation=Vacation{id=2, vacationTitle='Italy', description='Visit Italy', travelPrice=1000, imageUrl='some-image-url', excursions=null, createdAt=null, lastUpdate=null},
 excursions=[Excursion(id=2, excursion_title=Cheese Tour, excursion_price=100, image_URL='some-url', vacation=null, cartitems=null, createdAt=null, lastUpdate=null)],
 cart=null,
 createdAt=null,
 lastUpdate=null}
]
}

Edit #2: I tried modifying my CartItem. See comment.
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart_items")
@Data
public class CartItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cart_item_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Vacation vacation;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Excursion> excursions;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id") // i added this line
    private Cart cart;
}

Now I have a similar error: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'cart_id' cannot be null
I also spotted this potentially useful error: o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'cart_id' cannot be null
The final Hibernate log I see is
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        cart_items
        (cart_id, create_date, last_update, vacation_vacation_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)

Edit #3: I see in other threads about my new (related) error that "Since you defined a bidirectional relationship, you have to set the relation in both Answer and Question entities:"
So I tried to do
        for (CartItem item : cartItemsFromPurchase) {
            cart.addItem(item);
            item.setCart(cart);
        }

thinking maybe it would solve my "cart id" issue. Since the Cart's Cart Items have a cart field, and the field is null, perhaps the circular setting has to be. But no, I get a stack overflow:
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.iterator(HashSet.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:120) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.myproj.entity.Customer.hashCode(Customer.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.myproj.entity.Cart.hashCode(Cart.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.myproj.entity.CartItem.hashCode(CartItem.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.myproj.entity.Cart.hashCode(Cart.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.myproj.entity.CartItem.hashCode(CartItem.java:21) ~[classes/:na]

So that isn't the answer

Have you tried adding a PRIMARY KEY constraint on the table to cart_id?

I neglected to add that to the stackoverflow post. It was there all along. Admittedly I didn't read it clearly

Do you have some value assigned to this property in your yaml/properties file?
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
I faced a similar issue once before due to that property

I gave a few different settings a try, no change. spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update as well as create-drop & validate

I have faced the similar issued when I was trying to create the entity object manually and not setting any default value to my PRIMARY KEY as I was using the generated value. Later I used a random value of my PRIMARY KEY which was not in my DB and it is overwritten by JPA while saving the data to the table.

You might be facing another issue, please provide more code on how you are creating someNewCart variable to make it easier to help you.


I updated my OP with more content. I doubt it's a matter of how the Cart object is created, because it's data from the client and hasn't entered the database. It could be that the data doesn't conform to some required shape, fill in some required parameters. Or maybe it's the entities. I wish I knew

I found some success bypassing this error by

Removing ALL the associated cart items from the cart.
Saving the cart without the cart items.
Readding the cart items.

Set<CartItem> storage = cart.getCartItems();
Cart cartWithTheItemsRemoved = cart;
cartWithTheItemsRemoved.emptyTheCart();
cartRepository.save(cartWithTheItemsRemoved);

I expected JPA to handle creating the relations for me, but it didn't.
I can't tell if this other change was required:
// in my CartItem class
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id") // I added this
    private Cart cart;

I am still unable to save the cart items individually with the error java.sql.SQLException: Field 'vacation_id' doesn't have a default value but since it's similar to the previous iteration of this problem, I expect I will bypass it in a similar way.
